# UIButton in UIView as a subview not Tapping(No Action, No Colour Change)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uibutton, subview

I have a UIView that is a subview of a `UINavigationController`
Ex.

```
- (void) ViewDidload{
    UIView *theSubView = [[UIView alloc] init];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton . . . .]
    . . . .
    [theSubView addSubView:button];
    [self.view addSubview:theSubView];
}
```

All the labels and buttons i put inside "theSubView" SHOW UP but they dont response to any touch.

The `UIButton` WORKS if it in NOT a subview of "theSubView" but when it is a subview of self it works.

So my question is how do i make the Button inside "TheSubView" (UIView) work??
It doesn't light up or anything.

Answer (score 10):

If I'm correct then you problem is actually that you use

```
[[UIView alloc] init]
```

instead of the designated initializer

```
initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
```

You are creating a view who's bounds are 0,0. You should create it using the designated initializer and do something like this

```
/*
 * note that the values are just sample values.
 * the view's origin is  0,0 and it's width 320, it's height 480
*/
UIView *theSubView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480];
```

If you set

```
theSubView.clipsToBounds = YES
```

the result should be that you won't see your button at all, because the view's size is 0,0.

A UIView can only respond to touches inside his own bounds, this is why your button doesn't respond to any touches.

Comment: @TonyHoang if it works then please accept it as correct answer :)